# AngularJS leaflet issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, leaflet

i'm making a little app for personal training with AngularJS, and I have a problem... I'm using lealet, and an API to receive data and display it in my map. Everything work fine, except that i have the next error in the console :

[AngularJS - Leaflet]  The "center" property is not defined in the main scope

here is my controller code :

```
toulouseVeloControllers.controller('toulouseVeloDetailCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$http',
  function($scope, $routeParams, $http) {
    $http.get('https://api.jcdecaux.com/vls/v1/stations/' + $routeParams.bornesnumber + '?contract=Toulouse&apiKey=***********************').success(function(data) {

      $scope.bornes = data;


        angular.extend($scope, {
            osloCenter: {
                lat: 59.91,
                lng: 10.75,
                zoom: 12
            },
            markers: {
                osloMarker: {
                    lat: data.position.lat,
                    lng: data.position.lng,
                    message: data.name,
                    focus: true,
                    draggable: false
                }
            },
            defaults: {
                scrollWheelZoom: false
            }
        });
    });
  }]);
```

And here goes my HTML code :

```
<div ng-controller="toulouseVeloDetailCtrl">
    <leaflet markers="markers" center="osloCenter" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></leaflet>
</div>
```

Somenone have an idea of why it's failing ?

Thank you a lot !

Comment: Did you include a real API key by accident in the code above?

Comment: Yes it was by accident. Tx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$scope.osloCenter isn't defined until the http request completes. Move it outside of the http success function.

```
toulouseVeloControllers.controller('toulouseVeloDetailCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$http',
  function($scope, $routeParams, $http) {

     angular.extend($scope, {
                osloCenter: {
                    lat: 59.91,
                    lng: 10.75,
                    zoom: 12
                },
                markers: {},
                defaults: {
                    scrollWheelZoom: false
                }
            });
    $http.get('https://api.jcdecaux.com/vls/v1/stations/' + $routeParams.bornesnumber + '?contract=Toulouse&apiKey=***********************').success(function(data) {

      $scope.bornes = data;

      $scope.markers.osloMarker = {
                        lat: data.position.lat,
                        lng: data.position.lng,
                        message: data.name,
                        focus: true,
                        draggable: false
                    }            
    });
  }]);
```